# $.ajax beforesend is not working with async: false

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui

In the below code I am not able to open the dialog box of 'Personal Information' which is under the `beforeSend` function. If I remove `async: false` then I am able to see that.

Is there any other alternative for async that I can use?

```js
$.ajax({
  url: "<%=request.getContextPath()%>/url.do",
  type: 'GET',
  data: data,
  cache: false,
  dataType: 'text',
  async: false,
  beforeSend: function() {
    $.blockUI({
      theme: true,
      fadeIn: 0,
      title: "Personal Information",
      message: "Saving information...",
      timeout: 3000
    });
  }
```

Comment: `async:false` is not `async` ... it's `not async` ... don't use syncrhonous gets in the main thread, it's deprecated in all brwosers worth using - the solution is to remove `async:false` ... why is that an issue?

Comment: @JaromandaX  actually, this is a child method in the parent method there is one more dialog box that will appear once done with this dialog box. But if I have removed async from here it is showing me this dialog box but that parent method dialog box is not showing

Comment: In that case you need to invoke your dialogs from the callbacks of the chained AJAX requests. `async: false` is never a workable solution. If you need more specific help with this, please edit the question to include details of both requests and dialogs, and when they should be triggered to appear.

Comment: without all the code you are having an issue with, there's no way to answer ... but .. definitely DO NOT have `async:false` unless you're in a web worker (which you wouldn't be) ... do you know what `beforeSend` is used for? hint: it's NOT to display dialogs or whatever ... it's to modify the jqXHR object prior to making the request - usually you wouldn't put an inline function, usually it's some function you've defined to tweak the jqXHR object before each send ... so, in reality, you're misusing that calllback anyway